# Python's Abstract class doesn't return error on instantiation of incomplete concrete class

Tags: c#, python, abstract-class

I am a programmer who is used to programming in C# and I am trying to implement functionality similar to C#'s interfaces using python's abstract class.

### C#

If I would want to make sure that a certain class, Concrete in the following example, has certain properties or methods I would create an interface, IBase, and make sure that this class implements this interface. The compiler would then return an error if the class doesn't implement every required method and property.

Example:

```
public interface IBase
    {
        void Foo();
        void Bar();
    }

    public class Concrete : IBase
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo is implemented");
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
Program.cs(25,33): error CS0535: 'Program.Concrete' does not implement interface member 'Program.IBase.Bar()'
```

### Python (2.7)

I tried to achieve something similair in python (2.7). By creating an abstract class, Base, with abstract methods and making the class Concrete a subclass from this abstract class. What should happen is that the console would throw an error when instantiating an object if it doesn't obtain all the required methods and properties, but in the following example the program seems to run fine untill the missing function actually get's called.

Example:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Base:
    _metaclass_ = ABCMeta

@abstractmethod
def Foo(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()

@abstractmethod
def Bar(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()

class Concrete(Base):
    def Foo(self):
        print "Foo is implemented"

c = Concrete()
c.Foo()
c.Bar()
```

Result:

```
Foo is implemented
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 27, in <module>
      c.Bar()
  File "temp.py", line 19, in Bar
      raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me what's going wrong.

Comment: `'_metaclass_' != '__metaclass__'`. Also your indentation seems off and you should be using new-style classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@johnsharpe's comment is correct:

```
class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod
    def Foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    @abstractmethod
    def Bar(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Concrete(Base):
    def Foo(self):
        print 'Foo is implemented'



>>> c = Concrete()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    c = Concrete()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Concrete with abstract methods Bar
>>>
```